# Pass value to app.js file to show in header

Tags: reactjs

My home page has a drop down, I want to pass the selected value to the app.js file which has a header and a menu, I want that selected value to appear in the header which is on the app.js file, is that possible?

my home.js code:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [ environment, setEvironment ] = useState([]);

  const ddOnChange = async (e) => {
    setEnvironment(e.target.value);
  } 


  return (
     <select className="dropdown main" onChange={ ddOnChange }>
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="NW">Northwest</option>
        <option value="SE">South East</option
     </select>
  )
}
export default Home;
```

Is there a way to pass that environment value to the app.js file so it appears in the menu header on that page?

Comment: Just make `environment` a state variable in `app.js` and pass it to `Home` via props

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js define a state and pass it's setter to your home:

```
const [activeHeader, setActiveHeader] = React.useState();
return (
    ......
    <Home setActiveHeader={setActiveHeader} />
    ......
)
```

Then in your Home.js, update the state using the setter:

```
const Home = ({setActiveHeader}) => {

  const ddOnChange = async (e) => {
    setActiveHeader(e.target.value);
  } 


  return (
     <select className="dropdown main" onChange={ ddOnChange }>
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="NW">Northwest</option>
        <option value="SE">South East</option
     </select>
  )
}
export default Home;
```